# How to copy an ancestor to a descendant

Tags: java, inheritance, copy, clone

Let's say I have an animal and now I want to make it a dog. How do I go about doing this in java?

Right now I have a constructor that looks like

```
public Dog(Animal animal) {
  this.setProperty(animal.getProperty);
  ...
}
```

While this works, it's fragile. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What are you interested in accomplishing:
1) Taking an generic instance of Animal and using it to create a more specialized instance of Dog? 
OR
2) Taking a specialized instance of some Animal subclass other than Dog and using it to create a new instance of Dog.

I am assuming that Dog is a subclass of Animal since you are asking about "[copying] an ancestor to a descendant"

Comment: I have an instance of an "Animal" and want to turn it into an instance of a "Dog", then add all my dog specific properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Dog extends Animal, you can create a constructor that takes an Animal and initializes the super(parent) constructor:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog(Animal animal) {
        super(animal);
    }
}
```

Assuming you have an Animal class that has a copy constructor in this form:

```
public class Animal {
    public Animal(Animal animal) {
        // copies all properties from animal to this
    }
}
```

You can create a Dog from an Animal by doing something like this:

```
Dog newDog = new Dog(myExistingAnimal);
```

Comment: That's more or less the same solution I have now, except that the copy code is in the descendant. 

This does improve the design, but it still feels like there should be a better solution available.

What about using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

Try and use a factory. Rather than basing it on the constructor, use a factory to return a specific type of Animal based on whatever is your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure precisely what you want, so I'm going to assume you want the Animal object upgraded in place to be a Dog object.

```
class AnimalImpl {
    // ...
}

class DogImpl extends AnimalImpl {
    // ...
}

class Animal {
    private AnimalImpl implementation;
    public Animal() {
        implementation = new AnimalImpl;
    }
    public void becomeADog() {
        implementation = new DogImpl(implementation);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Animal animal = getAnAnimalFromSomewhere();
// `animal` has generic Animal behaviour
animal.becomeADog();
// `animal` now has Dog behaviour
```

This might not be what you want, but it can be useful when an object should have substantially different behaviour, depending on its state.